# YII2 use active record with “join with“, I think these Sql shouldnt excute

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

Why these sql is execute I think the the "joinWith" finsh all work

[image]
* this is my Model 
  [image]

`php
    $query = Teacher::find()->select([
            '{{%teacher}}.id','{{%teacher}}.nickname','{{%teacher}}.type_id','{{%teacher}}.header_img','{{%teacher}}.type_id',
            '{{%teacher}}.edu_area_deep3','{{%teacher}}.edu_level','{{%teacher}}.edu_class','{{%teacher}}.college_graduate_id',
            '{{%teacher}}.sex',
 '{{%teacher}}.edu_count_time','{{%teacher}}.edu_count_number','{{%teacher}}.teach_subject',
            '{{%teacher}}.specialty','{{%teacher}}.reward_count','{{%teacher}}.oneself'
        ])->joinWith(['typeName','eduLevel','collegeGraduate'])->asArray();`

Comment: please give more info. show us your controller action and view codes

Comment: looks like the first query is only populating data for the primary model
and not populating relations; add the code that you use to generate these queries please

Comment: sorry  I edited the question again